# Load .npy file from a shared network drive

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, unc, shared-directory

I have a .npy file that I have tested loading locally and it works fine, but when I put it in a shared drive then python never completes the task of loading the file.
I have to reboot my program in order to run it again.

This is my code:

```
 import os
 import numpy as np
 if os.path.isfile('\\\\randomNetwork\\share$\\randomFile.npy'):
        daCorpus = np.load('\\\\randomNetwork\\share$\\randomFile.npy')
```

My program enters the condition but runs infinitely. I am using Python 3.6.4.

UPDATE:
After letting my program run for 20 minutes it finally loads the .npy file without errors which takes about 1 second when it is stored locally. I don't believe this is fixable. I will leave this question up in case someone runs into something similar.

Comment: Why not copy it to a local drive using shutil.copy, then load as normal? What is the advantage of reading over the network? Also, you can use raw strings: r"\\regular\path"

Comment: I guess copying the file just feels like an extra unnecessary step. But if that's what I have to do then I will

Comment: Also, copying from the network is incredibly slow with a large file